# renaming file based on if it exists

Tags: c#

I am currently dealing with an issue in iPads were when you upload an image via my site the image is renamed to "image.jpg" which is an issue as if it's in the same directory it can cause issues.. so I am trying to stop it renaming the file OR to add an incremental number onto the end of it, however I can't get this to function correctly.

I have used this small snippet of code to try and fix it, however it doesn't seem to work.

```
if(File.Exists(filename))
{
    fileName = String.Format("{0}({1}", fileName, count++);
    inputFile.PostedFile.SaveAs( String.Format( "{0}\\{1}", directory, fileName ) );
}
else
{
    inputFile.PostedFile.SaveAs( String.Format( "{0}\\{1}", directory, fileName ) );
}
                    }
```

Comment: Could be just a typo, but you have `filename` in the `File.Exists` check and `fileName` everywhere else. C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: `File.Exists(filename)` should work fine.Maybe check the `count`?Is it same value every time cause the problem?

Comment: that was a typo, but it still doesn't work :P

Answer (score 1):

`File.Exists(filename)` expects complete file path to see if the file exists or not.

but in the line `inputFile.PostedFile.SaveAs`, you are concatenating filepath to be

`directory + "//" + fileName`.

so does your `fileName` actually consists of fullpath, or just the actual  filename with extension?

if `fileName` consists of fullPath, `inputFile.PostedFile.SaveAs` should not work, as it would point to invalid location, and if `fileName` consists of just the file name and not complete path, then, `File.Exists` should not work. either way your logic is flawed.

I guess, now you know, what to change.

also, instead of using a counter, simply append `DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmddttmmss")` to the `fileName` to make it unique.

Comment: Too quick Manish! the DateTime approach is definitely a good tip

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString("hhttmmss")` does not guarantee uniqueness. Two files could be uploaded at the same time. `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` would be better.

Comment: I never thought about using a date time format for doing this, appreciate it!

Comment: @GregB it will, simply increase the precision! Besides, yes, generating NewGuid is again a good way

Comment: Instead of `DateTime.Now.ToString(...)` IMHO it's better to use `DateTime.Now.Ticks`

Answer (score 1):

When you call:

```
if(File.Exists(filename))
```

Make sure that filename includes the full path on disk to where you save the files.

From the looks of it you may want to use Path.Combine(directory, fileName) rather than just filename on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the filename as

```
filename = filename + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
```

so that it will always be the new file. I mean it will retain the old as well as new file.

I hope it will help you.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    fileName= Path.Combine(directory,fileName );
    if(File.Exists(filename))
    {
        fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.Ticks;         
    }
    inputFile.PostedFile.SaveAs( fileName );
```